# Shuffle and display images from a directory in PHP

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to get the uploaded images from a directory and shuffle their order. I'm able to get the images and display them in order quite easily but can't seem to get them shuffled!

```
<?php 
    $imagesDir = 'uploads/';
    $images = glob($imagesDir . '*.{jpg,jpeg,png,gif}', GLOB_BRACE);
    $randomImage = $images[array_rand($images)]; 
?>

<div id="images">
        <?php
            $print_r($images);
            $shuffleimages = shuffle($images);
            foreach($shuffleimages as $shuffleimage) {
                echo '<img src="'.$shuffleimage.'" />';
            }
        ?>
</div>
```

When I print `$images` I get:

```
Array (

[0] => uploads/image1.jpg

[1] => uploads/image2.jpg

[2] => uploads/image3.jpg

[3] => uploads/image4.jpg

[4] => uploads/image5.jpg

)
```

I don't know if it's something to do with the glob function or how I'm retrieving the images more generally? I've looked around other questions on SO but can't seem to see what I'm doing differently/wrong!

Comment: Note that PHP's [`shuffle()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shuffle.php) returns a boolean value. So, in your case, `$shuffleimages` will be either `true` or `false` rather than a shuffled array. Also, where are you printing `$images` -- before or after the shuffle?

Comment: Thank you! & apologies (re the print), that was unclear – I printed it before the shuffle, will edit the question now

Comment: Gotcha okay. Yeah, the shuffle is probably working fine. It's just that you're outputting the original array before the shuffle and then attempting to loop through a boolean value rather than the shuffled array. Zak's got it working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are going one step too far .. There is no need to reassign `$images` ... Your `$shuffleimages` will only return a boolean of `true` or `false`

```
    <?php
        shuffle($images); // $images will be shuffled.
        foreach($images as $shuffleimage) {
            echo '<img src="'.$shuffleimage.'" />';
        }
    ?>
```

Comment: Thank you for this, really clears it up – I was unsure what it returned and couldn't seem to work out how to find out what it returned! I actually want to display the images in order later on in the page (this part I left out of the question) so was trying to keep the `$images` array as it was. I've fixed the problem by adding another variable at the top: `$shuffleImages = glob($imagesDir . '*.{jpg,jpeg,png,gif}', GLOB_BRACE);` underneath where I define `$images` and then shuffling that. But I was wondering whether you can think of a better way to do it all in this section of the code?

Comment: @JackClarke Rather than using `glob()` twice, I suggest: `$shuffleImages=$images; shuffle($shuffleImages);`

Comment: @showdev – OK, have put that in and it works perfectly – thank you! Can I ask (mostly out of curiosity) why this is preferable? Why not use `glob()` twice?

Comment: @JackClarke I assume glob takes longer to perform than duplicating a variable. I'm thinking: once I write down all the objects in my kitchen drawer, I can just photocopy the list rather than looking in the drawer a second time.

Comment: @showdev a perfect explanation! I'll keep the kitchen drawer in mind for the future

Answer (score 0):

You also may use [**`sacndir`**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php) and use the `sorting_order` parameter to shuffle files by sorting them.

Comment: Would be neat if there was a `SCANDIR_SORT_RANDOM` value.

Comment: Indeed, I could not able to understand the logic behind what you called `Random Sort`. There is no random sorting in our world, i.e sorting is kind of contraries of randomization! @showdev